# query a datetime field with just date in django

Tags: django

I am trying to query datetime field in django like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mr-check/?cname=4&date=2021-09-13+00:09
```

and views:

```
    cname = request.GET['cname']
    date = request.GET['date']
    # try:
    items = MaterialRequest.objects.filter(owner=cname).filter(delivery_required_on=d)
```

models:

```
delivery_required_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

now obviously I don't have an exact instance with `2021-09-13+00:09` but I have instances for the same date, how do I query a datetime field with just date?

Comment: Can you try to be more clear please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#id4) field lookup.  This casts the value as a date.

```
MaterialRequest.objects.filter(owner=cname).filter(delivery_required_on__date=d)
```

Also allows chaining additional field lookup, such as `gte`:

```
MaterialRequest.objects.filter(owner=cname).filter(delivery_required_on__date__gte=d)
```